# Gradle custom plugin jar with dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build a jar for a custom gradle plugin to be used by other gradle projects.  I'm using java to write the plugin.  I'm having a problem including dependencies in my jar.  If I build the jar using the below `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0-jre'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
}

group = 'com.mine'
version = '1.0'
```

I get a NoClassDefFound exception for guava classes when applying the plugin on a project.  If I include a task to create a jar with dependencies like below in the `build.gradle`

```
jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
}
```

It says `Plugin with Id 'my-plugin' not found`.  How do I include dependencies in a gradle plugin jar?

Comment: Don't build a jar and manually use the jar. Just publish the plugin to a Maven repository. Then the dependencies should be resolved automatically when it is used.

Answer (score 3):

Your plugin project should be configured as a standalone Plugin project and then published to a maven repository, which will make dependencies resolution work;  there is good documentation about writing custom plugin [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html), specially the following part : [using Gradle plugin development plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:using_the_java_gradle_plugin_development_plugin)

There is also a good example of writing/publishing/consuming a custom Plugin in the Gradle examples here : https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/plugins  (see the two subprojects `publishing` and `consuming` )

And here is a working example with a plugin that has dependency on external library (commons-lang for example):

**Plugin project**

*build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
group 'org.gradle.sample.plugin'
version '0.1'

//  pugin metadata configuration
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        myplugin {
            id = "org.gradle.sample.plugin.myplugin"
            implementationClass = "org.gradle.sample.plugin.MyPlugin"
        }
    }
}
// publish to local maven repo for testing
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "../repos/maven-repo"
        }
    }
}
//  repo for dependences resolution
repositories{
    jcenter()
}

// dependencies of this plugin 
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8.1'
}
```

*Plugin implementation* :  `src/main/groovy/org/gradle/sample/plugin/MyPLugin.groovy`

```
package org.gradle.sample.plugin

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(final Project project) {
        println "Applying custom plugin... "
        project.tasks.create('testPlugin'){
            doLast{
                println " custom plugin task executing."
                println "Result: " + StringUtils.capitalize("stringtotest")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Build and publish this plugin `./gradlew publish` : the plugin jar and "plugin marker artefacts" will be published to local maven repo in *../repos/maven-repo*

**Consumer project**

*build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    // import/apply your custom plugin
    id 'org.gradle.sample.plugin.myplugin' version '0.1'
}

group 'org.gradle.sample.plugin'
version '0.1'

repositories{
    maven {
        url "../repos/maven-repo"
     }
    jcenter()
}
```

To test the plugin, try to execute the plugin task `testPlugin`

```
> Task :testPlugin
 custom plugin task executing. 
 Result: Stringtotest
```

Comment: Hi I was curious if you can also provide example for gradle plugin with local dependencies for example with dependency for my local module (which I have written; in other words not external dependency). I am struggling with publishing it to MavenLocal; after using that plugin in my other project I will get error that artifact for my local module was not found. To clarify I have the same problem as here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831685/how-to-publish-and-use-gradle-plugin-with-dependencies-on-local-project.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the dependency is a local subproject. I get the error `Could not find io.github.sof3:core:1.0-SNAPSHOT.`, where my plugin is `io.github.sof3:plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to add this as an answer but I don't have enough points to comment (yes it is a bit late in coming but I found this in a search and it came so close, maybe this will help someone else).

The answer by @M.Ricciuti is correct, just missing one file, namely a settings.gradle in the referencing project (not the plugin) directory:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url '../repos/maven-repo'
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        ivy {
            url '../repos/ivy-repo'
    }
}
```

}

Many thanks, I have tried many things that didn't work before finding this, even the examples by gradle didn't work (or more likely I didn't run them correctly).  Anyway I merged what I saw in the answers with M. Ricciuti's answer and saw that file in the sample.

My complete project is at https://github.com/reddierocket/sampleGradlePlugin
The readme has instructions to run it.  (Note I did not include the wrapper but I am using gradle version 5.3.1.)