# How to publish and use gradle plugin with dependencies on local project?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am creating gradle plugin which has dependency on my other local module. Some of its gradle build look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile project(":myDependencyProject")

}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'org.my.gradle.plugin'
            artifactId = 'some-name'
            version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        jsonPlugin {
            id = 'org.my.gradle.plugin'
            implementationClass = 'my.implementation.class'
        }
    }
}
```

When I publish my plugin using **gradle publishToMavenLocal** and after that I try to use that plugin in another project it fails with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':my-project'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':my-project:classpath'.
   > Could not find org.my.gradle.plugin:myDependencyProject:1.0-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations: ...
```

In simple words it could not find dependency for myDependencyProject project. That is why as a next step I tried to create a fat jar and publish it but I have got the same error (the code for gradle plugin was same except I have changed `from components java` to `artifact shadowJar`).

Can someone help me how can I publish gradle plugin with its local dependencies and use it in another project ?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up using the [Gradle shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to include our module in the [published artifact](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/publishing/).

One thing that was important to us though, was to only include the local library in it to prevent our end consumer from having 2 copies of some library (such as Kotlin). So we [filtered the dependencies](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/dependencies/#filtering-dependencies)

```
shadowJar {
   dependencies {
      include(dependency(':your-module-name:'))
   }
}
```